# Confusion in Maxwell's derivation of Ampere's Force Law

Tags: electromagnetism

I am reading Maxwell's "a treatise on electricity and magnetism, Volume 2, page 155" about "Ampere's Force Law". I have some confusion in the following pages:

[image]

[image]

On the top of the page, Maxwell says: (The coordinates of points on either current are functions of s or of s')

Does he mean we parametrize the path of one circuit with variable s and another circuit with variable s'?

Then he says: (If F is any function of the position of a point, then we shall use
the subscript$_{(s,0)}$ to denote the excess of its value at P over that
at A, thus
$$F_{(s,0)}=F_{P}-F_{A}$$
Such functions necessarily disappear when the circuit is closed.)

Does he mean$$\oint F.ds = 0$$ or something else?

If he means something else by "Such functions necessarily disappear when the circuit is closed" what is it?

[image]

Comment: You must go back to page 511 and  therein Figure 29. Image of this page has been added to your question. 
The variables $\:s\:$ and $\:s^{\prime}\:$ parametrize the two curves and more exactly are arc lengths from 
reference points $\:A\:$ and $\:A^{\prime}\:$ respectively.

Comment: On the other hand  by  _"If  F is any function ..."_  this function is not necessarily a vector function to use in a curvilinear integral $\:\int_{C} \mathbf{F}\cdot d \mathbf{s} \:$. The "disappearence" of  $\:F_{(s,0)}=F_{P}-F_{A}\:$ in case of a closed curve is due simply to the coincidence of the final point $\: P\:$  with the initial point $\: A\;$.

Comment: OK thanks, I understand s and s' parametrize the two curves.

Comment: I understand this. But in page 156, article 517, equation 19 there is a term 2Pr added inside the integral. I was considering it as a conservative vector field when dotted with ds' and integrated around closed path gives zero. Am I right or wrong? Please explain why that term 2Pr is added inside the integral in equation 19.

Comment: On one hand, what is the relation of equation (19) with my comment about the function $\:F\:$ ??? On the other hand, must I read all the Chapter to explain what 2 is, what  $\:P\:$  is, why  $\:2Pr\:$  is inserted in an integral ?? You are reading the book by yourself. Continue trying to understand the ingenious Maxwell's thoughts and writings.

Comment: Please try reading the chapter at least from article 511 and please explain why 2Pr is inserted inside the integral. I asked my physics teacher but he couldn't understand and suggested me not to read old books. But anyway I am reading it because that is only where I find a historic derivation of Ampere's Force Law. I hope you will find it easy.

Comment: I know integration by parts. But which term in equation 18 should we integrate by parts?? Is it B+C (It is not a product of two functions). Anyway we can find $$\int A+Bdr$$ by integration by parts to get$$ r^{2} P-\int 2Prdr$$. But it does'nt show how 2Pr got added inside the integral. Please tell me how, by integration by parts, 2Pr can be added inside the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

\begin{align} \int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}\dfrac{dP}{ds^{\prime}} \xi^{2}ds^{\prime} & = \biggl[P\xi^{2}\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}} -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P d\xi^{2}\\ & = \biggl[P\xi^{2}\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}}-\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}2P \xi d\xi\\ & =  \biggl[P\xi^{2}\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}}-\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}2P \xi \underbrace{\dfrac{d\xi}{ds^{\prime}}}_{=l ^{\prime}}ds^{\prime}\\ & =\biggl[P\xi^{2}\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}} -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}2P \xi l ^{\prime}ds^{\prime} \end{align}

Comment: While the OP may have found this helpful, to make a lasting, useful resource for future visitors this post *does* need additional clarification of what you're plotting and calculating, and why.

Comment: What software are you plotting with?

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty : This answer was a comment at the begining. I tried to help without answering.  But later on I answered  to an additional question on the same problem here : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257127/confusion-in-maxwells-derivation-of-amperes-force-law-part-ii/258416#258416,  a question already on hold. I don't  think that these questions and answers are useful to the broader community, and to future users. The present question must be put on hold too.

Comment: @ WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance : **GeoGebra**  free amazing software. It accepts text and equations in LateX as you see in the Figures. I saw this software last year as suggested tool in the right column of Physics SE. You will be surprised for its capabilities in a day by day use.

Comment: @Frobenius Fair enough. That's plotted with GeoGebra? I might need to give it a closer look, then.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty : I tried to sketch two curves at random (they represent two circuits with currents $\:i\:$ and   $\:i'\:$ in Maxwell' s notation). Instead of  joining circular arcs and segments in space, I gave the parametric equations at random as follows :
1. Geogebra command for left unprimed curve  : **Curve[8cos(t) + 5, 4sin(t) - 5, t - 4, t, 7, 9.5]**
The point P is  at  t=8.2. A vector tangent to the curve at point  P  is of course [-8sin(t),4cos(t),1]  at t=8.2 
(continues)

Comment: 2. Geogebra command for right primed curve  : **Curve[12sin(t), 3cos(2t) + 2, 0.3t, t, 8.7, 10.5]**
The point P' is  at  t=9.5. A vector tangent to the curve at point  P'  is of course [12cos(t),-6sin(t),0.3]  at t=9.5
Take a look here :   http://i.imgur.com/v0q7VXn.jpg

Comment: @ Frobenius: Please (if possible) give your rough gmail id. I can give you my questions there through my gmail (faheemahmed6000@gmail.com). If you have no rough gmail, please make a new one.By rough gmail id, I mean that gmail id which you don't use for personal or official purposes.