# Confusion in Maxwell's derivation of Ampere's Force Law - Part II

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I am reading Maxwell's "a treatise on electricity and magnetism, Volume 2, page 156" about "Ampere's Force Law". I have some confusion in the following pages:

[image]

[image]

**My question is of two parts:**

**1.** Equation 20, i.e. $P=\dfrac{B+C}{2r}$ is the outcome of special case *(i.e. l=1, m=0, n=0)*

But in Page 156, Article 517, Maxwell says: "We can now eliminate P, and find the general value of $\dfrac{dX}{ds}$" and uses this formula (i.e. $P=\dfrac{B+C}{2r}$) in the general case.

However in the general case, where *0 < l, m, n < 1*, and hence
$$\dfrac{d^{2}X}{dsds'}=l\left( \frac{dP}{ds'}\xi^{2}-\dfrac{dQ}{ds'}+(B+C)\dfrac{l'\xi}{r}\right) +m(...)+n(...)\neq0$$ (since direction of X is not in the direction of ds)

therefore,
$$\dfrac{dX}{ds}=l\left[ (P\xi^{2}-Q)_{(s',0)}-\int\limits_0^s' (2Pr-B-C)\dfrac{l'\xi}{r}ds'\right] +m\int\limits_0^s'(...)ds'+n\int\limits_0^s'(...)ds'$$
Now in this general case, how can we get $P=\dfrac{B+C}{2r}$.

If $P\neq\dfrac{B+C}{2r}$ in general case, what does Maxwell mean by "We can now eliminate P, and find the general value of $\dfrac{dX}{ds}$"

**2.** How can one get equation 21 from equation 15. Please give a lengthy derivation.

Comment: **1**. What are $A$, $B$, and $C$? If they do not depend on $l$, $m$, $n$, then any property you find with specific values will be true for all values. Just as the equation $P=(B+C)/2r$ has been derived from the closed circuit case, and extended to all cases probably because the terms cannot depend on the circuit shape. **2**. Is there anything that prevents you from doing this derivation yourself?

Comment: A, B, and C are functions of r.

Comment: If A, B, and C do not depend on l, m and n; how can any property of specific values true for all values? Please explain with an example

Comment: I have no idea of how $\dfrac{B-C}{2}$ came into the expression. I also know that when $B+C=0$, and after integration with respect to ds', we can get equation 21 from equation 15. But how come $B+C=0$.If  $B+C=0$ is not valid then I have no idea how to get equation 21 from equation 15.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand how the example of the trajectory of a satellite relates to the question. Please explain a bit more clearly in the context of the above question.

Comment: For your first question, if $P=(B+C)/(2r)$ is valid for a special case, is there any reason it is not valid for a general case?

Comment: According to article 516, $P=\dfrac{B+C}{2r}$ only when l=1, m=0, n=0 and $\dfrac{dX}{ds}=0$. Please explain how can we generalise it for arbitrary values of l, m, n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANSWER TO QUESTION  1.**  *The distance $r$ between two points P and P' in space does not depend on the frame $Oxyz$. It's invariant.*

Suppose that we have two points P and P'  in space  at a distance $r$ apart and we want  to find a scalar function $P(r)$ that satisfies a number of conditions. Let  there exists a system of coordinates $Oxyz$ that is more convenient than others and makes my life easy to calculate and determine this scalar function $P(r)$, for example say that I find  $P(r)=3r^{3/2}-2$. This result is independent of the choice of system $Oxyz$ since  $r$ is the same in all systems. That what Maxwell did : He finds that a coordinate system  $Oxyz$ with its axis $Ox$ aligned with the tangent of the unprimed curve $\:\left(l=dx/ds=1, m=dy/ds=0, n=dz/ds=0 \right)\:$ at point P is more convenient  and reach to equation (20-in textbook), see below, which is independent of the system.

---

**ANSWER TO QUESTION  2.**  *The key for the solution is to understand the geometry of the problem and to know which variables depend on the lenght parameters $s,s'$ of the curves.*
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
\dfrac{dx}{ds}=l, & \dfrac{dy}{ds}=m, &\dfrac{dz}{ds}=n,\\
\dfrac{dx'}{ds'}=l', & \dfrac{dy'}{ds'}=m', &\dfrac{dz'}{ds'}=n',
\end{matrix} 
\tag{2-in textbook}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\xi = x'-x,   \qquad \eta = y'-y,  \qquad \zeta = z'-z.
\tag{under 12-in textbook}
\end{equation}

---

\begin{align}
\dfrac{d^{2}X}{dsds'} & =l\: \:\biggl\{ -\left( A+B \right)\dfrac{1}{r^{2}}\dfrac{dr}{ds'} \xi^{2}+C\dfrac{dr}{ds'}+\left( B+C \right)\dfrac{l'\xi}{r} \biggr\},\\
& +m \biggl\{ -\left( A+B \right)\dfrac{1}{r^{2}}\dfrac{dr}{ds'} \xi\eta+C\dfrac{l'\eta}{r}+B\dfrac{m'\xi}{r} \biggr\},\\
& +n \: \biggl\{ -\left( A+B \right)\dfrac{1}{r^{2}}\dfrac{dr}{ds'} \xi\zeta+C\dfrac{l'\zeta}{r}+B\dfrac{\eta'\xi}{r} \biggr\}.
\tag{15-in textbook}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
P=\int_{r }^{\infty}\left( A+B \right)\dfrac{1}{r^{2}}dr, \qquad \text{and} \qquad  Q=\int_{r }^{\infty}Cdr,
\tag{16-in textbook}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\text{Hence} \qquad   \left( A+B \right)\dfrac{1}{r^{2}}= - \dfrac{dP}{dr},  \qquad \text{and} \qquad   C= - \dfrac{dQ}{dr}. 
\tag{17-in textbook}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P=\dfrac{1 }{ 2r }\left( B+C\right)
\tag{20-in textbook}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
& \dfrac{dX}{ds}  =  \biggl\{\dfrac{ B+C}{2} \dfrac{\xi}{r}\left( l\xi+m\eta+n \zeta\right)-Q\biggr\}_{0}^{s'}\\
& +m \int_{0}^{s'} \dfrac{ B-C}{2} \dfrac{ m'\xi -l'\eta}{r}ds'-n\int_{0}^{s'} \dfrac{ B-C}{2} \dfrac{ l'\zeta-n'\xi}{r}ds'. 
\tag{21-in textbook}
\end{align}
In the textbook the minus sign of  $\:-Q\:$ in the first term of the rhs is probably misprinted as plus $\:+Q\:$.

---

The unit vector $\left(l,m,n\right)$ tangent to the uprimed curve at point P is dependent  on the length parameter $\;s\;$ but is independent of the length parameter $\;s'\;$ of the primed curve.. That's why these variables are outside of the integrals with respect to  $\;s'\;$ in the following integrations
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dX}{ds} & =l\: \:   \int_{0}^{s'}  \biggl\{ -\left( A+B \right)\dfrac{1}{r^{2}} \xi^{2}dr+Cdr+\left( B+C \right)\dfrac{l'\xi}{r}ds' \biggr\},\\
& +m    \int_{0}^{s'}    \biggl\{ -\left( A+B \right)\dfrac{1}{r^{2}} \xi\eta dr+C\dfrac{l'\eta}{r}ds'+B\dfrac{m'\xi}{r}ds' \biggr\},\\
& +n \:   \int_{0}^{s'}   \biggl\{ -\left( A+B \right)\dfrac{1}{r^{2}}\xi\zeta dr +C\dfrac{l'\zeta}{r}ds'+B\dfrac{\eta'\xi}{r} ds'\biggr\}.
\tag{A-01}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dX}{ds} & =l\: \:   \int_{0}^{s'}  \biggl\{ \xi^{2}dP-dQ+\left( B+C \right)\dfrac{l'\xi}{r}ds' \biggr\},\\
& +m    \int_{0}^{s'}    \biggl\{ \xi\eta dP+C\dfrac{l'\eta}{r}ds'+B\dfrac{m'\xi}{r}ds' \biggr\},\\
& +n \:   \int_{0}^{s'}   \biggl\{\xi\zeta dP +C\dfrac{l'\zeta}{r}ds'+B\dfrac{\eta'\xi}{r} ds'\biggr\}.
\tag{A-02}
\end{align}

---

In the following equations we make use of the integration by parts, we have in mind the definitions of the variables $\:l,m,n,l',m',n',\xi,\eta,\zeta \:$ and their dependence on (or  independence of) the length parameters $\;s,s'\;$ and the textbook equations (17) and (20), relations for functions $P(r)$ and $C(r)$ necessary to explain the results.
\begin{align}
 \int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}\xi^{2}dP 
& = \biggl[\xi^{2}P\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}} -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P d\xi^{2}\\
& = \biggl[P\xi^{2}\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}}-\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}2P \xi d\xi\\ 
& = \biggl[P\xi^{2}\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}}-\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}2P \xi \underbrace{\dfrac{d\xi}{ds^{\prime}}}_{=l ^{\prime}}ds^{\prime}\\
& = \biggl[P\xi^{2}\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}} -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}2P \xi l ^{\prime}ds^{\prime}\\
&=   \biggl[\dfrac{B+C}{ 2 } \dfrac{ \xi^{2}}{ r } \biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}} -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}\left( B+C \right)\dfrac{ l ^{\prime} \xi }{r}ds^{\prime}
\tag{A-03.$\xi\xi$}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}\xi\eta dP
& = \biggl[\xi\eta P\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}} -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P d\left(\xi\eta \right)\\
& = \biggl[P\xi\eta\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}}-\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P \xi d\eta-\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P\eta d\xi\\ 
& = \biggl[P\xi\eta \biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}}-\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P \xi \underbrace{\dfrac{d\eta}{ds^{\prime}}}_{=m ^{\prime}}ds^{\prime}
       - \int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P\eta \underbrace{\dfrac{d\xi}{ds^{\prime}}}_{=l ^{\prime}}ds^{\prime}\\
& = \biggl[ P\xi\eta \biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}} -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P\left(m'\xi + l'\eta \right)ds^{\prime}\\
& = \biggl[\dfrac{B+C}{ 2 } \dfrac{ \xi\eta}{ r } \biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}} -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}\dfrac{B+C}{ 2 }\dfrac{m'\xi + l'\eta }{r}ds^{\prime}
\tag{A-03.$\xi\eta$}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}\xi\zeta dP
& = \biggl[\xi\zeta P\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}} -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P d\left(\xi\zeta \right)\\
& = \biggl[P\xi\zeta\biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}}-\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P \xi d\zeta -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P \zeta d\xi \\ 
& = \biggl[P\xi\zeta \biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}}-\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P \xi \underbrace{\dfrac{d\zeta}{ds^{\prime}}}_{=n ^{\prime}}ds^{\prime}
       -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P \zeta \underbrace{\dfrac{d\xi}{ds^{\prime}}}_{=l ^{\prime}}ds^{\prime}\\
& = \biggl[ P\xi\zeta \biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}} -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}P\left(n' \xi +l'\zeta \right)ds^{\prime}\\
& = \biggl[\dfrac{B+C}{ 2 } \dfrac{ \xi\zeta}{ r } \biggr]_{0}^{s^{\prime}} -\int_{0}^{s^{\prime}}\dfrac{B+C}{ 2 }\dfrac{n'\xi + l'\zeta }{r}ds^{\prime}
\tag{A-03.$\xi\zeta$}
\end{align}

---

**EDIT**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The term with coefficient $l$ works fine.

But simplifying the term with coefficient $m$,

$$\int\limits_0^{s'}\left[-(B+C)\dfrac{m'\xi+l'\eta}{r} + B\dfrac{m'\xi}{r} + C\dfrac{l'\eta}{r}\right]ds'$$

$$=\int\limits_0^{s'}\left[-B\dfrac{l'\eta}{r} - C\dfrac{m'\xi}{r}\right]ds'$$

How shall I get $\int\limits_0^{s'}\dfrac{B-C}{2} \dfrac{m'\xi-l'\eta}{r}ds$ from here?

Comment: Please give a last explanation here. I have just passed high school and am new to this. You indeed helped a lot.

Comment: @faheemahmed400  : I apologize. Take a look at the new corrected equations $(A-03.\xi\eta)$ and $(A-03.\xi\zeta)$. I corrected an error with a coefficient 2 instead of 1. But now I have a problem with the sign of Q in the first braced term of (21). I find $(-Q)_{0}^{s'}$  but  in textbook is $(+Q)_{0}^{s'}$. The errata page doesn't refer to error in page 156 for this. May be I am wrong. I'll try to solve this contradiction.

Comment: @faheemahmed400  : So, in your above comment we have after the correction
$$
\int\limits_0^{s'}\left[-\dfrac{B+C}{2} \dfrac{m'\xi+l'\eta}{r} + B\dfrac{m'\xi}{r} + C\dfrac{l'\eta}{r}\right]ds'=\int\limits_0^{s'}\dfrac{B-C}{2} \dfrac{m'\xi-l'\eta}{r}ds'
$$
The same is valid for the term with coefficient $\;n$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But I think the $+Q$ in equation 21 is a misprint. Even in equation 19 its$ -Q$

Comment: @faheemahmed400 : Ok, Q-mystery solved.

Comment: @ Frobenius: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Please help me in my  future questions on the same topic.

Comment: @faheemahmed400 : With pleasure to help you, but  out of Physics SE because of the fact  than your questions and so my answers are off-topic, they are put on hold and later on will be closed. Indeed, they are not useful  to the broader community, and to future users. I can write my answers and upload them as pdf  document in a site, but the problem  is "wherein you'll post your questions ???".

Comment: @ Frobenius: Please (if possible) give your rough gmail id. I can give you my questions there through my gmail (faheemahmed6000@gmail.com). If you have no rough gmail, you can make a new one.By rough gmail id, I mean that gmail id which you don't use for any purpose.